# Python parser of ArcGIS Field calculator returns ERROR 000539: Error running expression?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, field-calculator, python-parser, error-000539

I like field calculator and use it often, however found something very disturbing today when attempted to do this on a table of 3D feature class.

```
def abc(shp,id):
 return shp.length
```

## ----------------------

```
abc( !Shape!, !UNIQID!)
```

Returns:

```
Executing: CalculateField LINES L abc( !Shape!, !UNIQID! ) PYTHON_9.3 "def abc(shp,id):\n return shp.length"
Start Time: Mon Sep 12 12:30:28 2016
ERROR 000539: Error running expression: abc( GPVARIANTOBJECT0, L1 ) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'L1' is not defined
```

On this table:

[image]

The same expression works fine on 2d features.
Moreover if I remove second argument and run it as:

```
def abc(shp):
 return shp.length
#----------------------
abc (!Shape!)
```

It also works as expected on table with 3D shapes.

So adding another variable to list of arguments results in a crush.

Somebody else can confirm this odd behaviour please.

I am working with 10.3.1 and it is happening only with second argument being text, numeric work fine.

I found a workaround by swapping arguments:
    abc(!UNIQID!,!Shape!)

Still weird.

**UPDATE after @Midavalo comment:**

Yes the same odd behaviour on 2D shapes

Comment: That is really odd, may be worth starting a support incident with ESRI so they can investigate and log it as a bug.

Comment: what type of file?  Shapefile or file gdb or other?

Comment: A quick test for me provided the same result, although for me it occurred on both the 2D and the 3D lines

Comment: I tested it on both shapefiles and FGDB classes

Comment: I agree with @crmackey - the best way forward is to log this with Esri Technical Support and, assuming that they can reproduce it, insist they provide a bug number that you can insert  into a self-answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a question such as this, where you have described what appears to be a reproducible bug, and has been verified by another member of our community, I think the best way forward is to log it with [Esri Technical Support](http://support.esri.com) and, assuming that they too can reproduce it, insist they provide a bug number that you can insert  into a self-answer to your own question.

Remember from the [help](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that:

> **We are not a GIS Software Support Site**. We encourage you to seek official routes for support for specific issues you may have.

Comment: You are right, however it is a nightmare to deal with Esri Support Page

Comment: It does seem to be getting worse. I really wish Esri accepted incident reports internationally in a single central simple location.